# install4j 5.1.5 - Signing: disable at command line or maven plugin not possible

Tags: signing, install4j

Today I integrated the signing process to our project. It works fine. Now I tried to disable the signing process at the maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.install4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>install4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-installer</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${install4j.projectFile}</projectFile>
                <destination>${project.build.directory}/installer</destination>
                <disableSigning>${disableSigning}</disableSigning>
                <!-- password for keystore has to be set as system property -->
                <winKeystorePassword>${certificate.keystore.psw}</winKeystorePassword>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I was calling our maven build with the following command:

```
mvn clean prepare-package -DdisableSigning=true
```

and got the following error message:

```
[INFO] --- install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.5:compile (build-installer) @ ForumViewerInstaller ---
[INFO] install4j: Unknown option '--disable-signing'
[INFO] Usage: install4jc [OPTIONS] [config file]
[INFO] Try 'install4jc --help for more information'
```

It looks like the maven-plugin is not compatible with install4j 5 anymore, is it? Or could it be a problem with my install4j configuration?

Thanks for any solution
Hardie

Comment: I tried the `install4jc.exe -u` option and that works fine. But when I switch to `install4jc.exe --disable-signing` I got the same error as with our maven build. Maybe thayt's a mapping problem with the command line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in install4j 5.1.11. Currently only the short form `-u` works.

Comment: Hi Ingo. Thanks for the information. Do you have a release date set for the version 5.1.11?

Comment: A couple of weeks, if you need it now, please contact support@ej-technologies.com for the current build